# REDCap how to show multiple choice options based on option selected from previous question

Tags: sql, multiple-choice, redcap

I recently started with REDCap, which sounds an easy tool to use. However, I was trying to add a question which would show options based on the selected option for the previous question. It's easier to explain with an example. Suppose I ask

1. Select the continent you live in (multiple choices: all continents)
2. Select the country you live in (if one selects Europe, only European countries would appear, but if one selected Africa, only countries from Africa and so on).

I could add a question with multiple choice for each continent and use branching logic, if Europe is selected, show question x1, if Africa, show question x2. But this seems a bit counterintuitive, in my opinion. I thought about using SQL but I'm not sure how I would populate the multiple choice question. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this? Pointers and recommended readings would be most appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a dropdown field for selecting the continent, and another dropdown field for selecting the country, you can create a custom validation equation for the country field that filters the list of countries based on the continent selected in the previous field.

1. First, create a drop-down field for selecting the continent. Set the
   field name to "continent" and add the list of continents as the
   answer choices.
2. Next, create a drop-down field for selecting the country. Set the
   field name to "country" and add all the countries as answer choices.
3. In the "country" field's "Custom Validation Equation" box, enter the
   following code:

   ```
   if (data['continent'] == 'Asia') {
       if (!['China', 'Japan', 'India'].includes(value)) {
           return 'Please select a country from Asia';
       }
   } else if (data['continent'] == 'Europe') {
       if (!['France', 'Germany', 'Italy'].includes(value)) {
           return 'Please select a country from Europe';
       }
   } else if (data['continent'] == 'North America') {
       if (!['United States', 'Canada', 'Mexico'].includes(value)) {
           return 'Please select a country from North America';
       }
   } else {
       return 'Please select a continent';
   }
   ```
4. Save the field and test the form. When you select a continent in the "continent" field, the list of countries in the "country" field will be filtered based on the selected continent. For example, if you select "Asia" in the "continent" field, the "country" field will only show "China", "Japan", and "India" as options.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Custom field validation types are only available to administrators? I cannot find the "Custom Validation Equation". Sorry if this is obvious, I just started using REDCap